# I am unable to output a pyramid in C++

Tags: c++

I wanted to make a pyramid like this:-

```
____*
___*_*
__*___*
_*_____*
*********
```

for n=5.
the lines are not underscores but spaces.

My try:-

```
#include <iostream.h>
void main()
{ int i,k,l,n;
 cin>>n;
 for(i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
     {
      for(k=1; k<=i; k++)
          {if((k==n+i-1)||(k==n-i+1))
             cout<<"*";
           else
             cout<<" ";
          }
      cout<<"\n";
     }
 for(l=1; l<=2*n-1; l++)
     cout<<"*";
 }
```

But the output comes as:-

```
__ *
 _*
```

---

Note: This is a turbo c++ program.

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

With some optimization and by taking n as row count instead of base width, we have something very simple:

```
void drawPyramid(const int &n) {
    int b=2*n-1;
    for (int i=b/2; i>=0; i--) {
        for (int j=0;j<b-i; j++) {
            if (i==0 || j==i || j==b-i-1) {
                std::cout<<"*";
            } else {
                std::cout<<" ";
            }
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

**Old:**

It was quite funny to do, but it works as well. My approach is to start a counter from the maximum width that the pyramid may have at the end, then divide the problem into two distinct steps:

1. Go to the first edge
2. Go to the second edge

It sure can be optimized but it will give you the idea:

```
int drawPyramid(const int &baseWidth, const char &edgeChar, const char &outsideChar, const char &insideChar) {
    // test if base width allows to have a single char at the top of it
    if (baseWidth%2==0) {
        std::cout<<"Error in 'drawPyramid(const int &baseWidth)': Pyramid base width must be an odd number for the top to match"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i=baseWidth; i>=0; i-=2) { // the first edge is initially far, then gets closer
        int j=0;

        // Go to first edge
        while (j<i/2) {
            std::cout<<outsideChar;
            j++;
        }
        std::cout<<edgeChar;

        if (i==1) { // at the bottom of the pyramid
            for (int k=0; k<baseWidth-1; k++) {
                std::cout<<edgeChar;
            }
        } else if (i<baseWidth) { // test if there is a second edge to reach
            // Go to second edge
            while (j<baseWidth-i/2-2) {
                std::cout<<insideChar;
                j++;
            }
            std::cout<<edgeChar;
        }

        // Done with the current line
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the lines are not required, those are just spaces, also is there any simpler version like mine? I don't know about those functions like std::, basewidth, etc

Comment: In fact, when you access `cout`, you are implicitly accessing it from std library. This is a good practice to explicitly access std features via the '::` operator so it clearly states that it's from std rather than defined somewhere else in your code. And yes, there probably is a simpler (math-based) version than that.

Comment: Your old answer's code is ***very*** slow. The update is a better one, although it could be speeded up too.

Comment: I agree, my old answer wasn't mathematical at all, hence very slow and terribly long :) However, I would be interested in a way to speed up the update. It seems to me that we can't go `O( n )` with that. Can we?

Comment: @dknight `O( n )` is the O-notation. You get `O( n^X )` when you have X nested loops of n iterations each. In other words, the most you can reduce the power of n, the faster it is supposed to be for a given n.

Answer (score 1):

modify your loop to this and it works

```
 for(i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
 {
  for(k=1; k<i + n; k++) // greater range than previously to include whole triangle
      {if((k==n+i-1)||(k==n-i+1)) // == instead of --
         cout<<"*";
       else
         cout<<" ";
      }
  cout<<"\n";
 }
 for(l=1; l<=2*n-1; l++)
```

Comment: Thats wierd my output is just right. What is your output of my version?

Comment: ___*
__*__*
_*____*
*______*
*********

Comment: I assume there is someone using unix/linux and someone using windows. Add a std:endl to the cout or flush the buffer

Comment: Did you try flushing your cout stream at the end?

Comment: Thats weird, is your code in your post your whole and exact program?

Comment: On my pc it is...
Try replacing "\n" with std::endl